# How to change default boot order ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

How can I change default boot order in Ubuntu 10.04 from Ubuntu to Windows7?

However, I already checked `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and modify the grub file to be 
GRUB_DEFAULT=4 and update the grup `sudo update-grub`

I even install graph software to re order the book `sudo startupmanager`

But still after restart the default choose for boot is Ubuntu ...

Thank you,
Sako Christian

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with grub version 1.98

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing recently.

> Actually very simple.  Use a text editor as "root" and edit the file
>   /boot/grub/grub.conf to change
>   defaults (no graphic config program
>   for grub).
>
> Look for the lines:
>   default=0
>   timeout=10
>   or something similar.
>
> Change the "default" number to
>   whichever position your Windows boot
>   info is in your list (start counting
>   at 0), and reboot.
>
> Since you only have the two OSs,
>   probably just change to default=1 and
>   you shoudl be all set.  If you want to
>   shorten the delay before the default
>   kicks in, "timeout" is the number of
>   seconds delay.
>
> Good luck.

From http://discuss.extremetech.com/forums/thread/1004322173.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `grub` config file:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

and update the line that starts with `default` to point to the entry that chainloads to Windows (I don't have Ubuntu but that's how I do normal everyday `grub` configuration.)

Comment: Actually, After I checked "grub-install -v" I noticed that I am using an old version of grub 0.98 instead the default version 1.98.
Problem fixed by restore the default version of grub. 

Thanks Jeff and Attila ;)

Comment: You're welcome. If you wait one day you can answer your own question and accept your own answer - just to help build the knowledge base of the site.